# Storing usernames and password

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, authentication, xcode5

right now I'm using Core Data - sqlite for database. And I have a few questions related to it.

I created a Modal with all the personal information of the user: username, date of birth, address, zip, state, etc... The password I'm using Keychain for login  functionality. So, my basic question is:

1. Where is this information stored? Locally in the user's iphone? But what if I have millions of users, wouldn't that database file be too big? Is it safe? I mean, users can see information of another users?
2. How can I edit that database if not programatically in xcode? I mean, what if I want to delete some user or change some specific information.

Thanks.

Comment: 1.millions user do not use same device.

Comment: I would use the keychain for this. More safe. And agree with @Virussmca

Comment: Yes, I want each user to use his own device. So that would work fine?

Answer (score 0):

1. Creating a local sqlite database on the device will only store the individual users info as each app is obviously stored on each device separately.  Users won't see each others info.
2. You will need to edit data in the database programatically via the app (ie code written in xcode)

Answer (score 0):

1. Keychain data will be stored inside a local db in the device. This is a shared db for several apps. So after you delete and reinstall the app, you will get the data. Million users may have their own devices. not logging in from a single device. The data in this keychain will be stored in the encrypted format. So you dont need to worry about the security.
   In iPhone simulator, the data will be stored in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<Version Number>/Library/Keychains/`
2. If you want to edit or delete the item, then try the below tutorial

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/03/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html

Answer (score 0):

if you use Core Data - sqlite for database then every user(device) has their own copy of databse.

so don't worry about file size & information of other users.

And you can edit that databse only by your app or by app's background Process in case of Core Data

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to known. Just a question, if some user deletes the app and reinstalled, I wouldn't lose his info, right?

Comment: In that case you lost that user's info not all. I mean all other user's data remain safe but you loast only info of that user who has deletes the app.

Comment: So how could I prevent this? My app is going to be a paid app (inside app), so I need to have the information about the user account (name, address, credit card, etc) in a safe place, and also being able to edit some specific information about that user. Thanks for the help.

Comment: for prevent the info of user who has deleted app.
you have only opetion is backend
for that you have to create DB on server & retrive data using API creted at backend
and no need to use Core Data.